# Recommended pattern for keeping ListView CursorAdapter data updated

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a SQLite table representing a to-do list. Each row has an `_id`, `title`, and a `completed` flag. I have a `ListView`, where each row has the title and a checkbox mapped to the `completed` flag. And I have a custom `CursorAdapter` that sets the checkbox state in `bindView`. The checkbox has an `OnClick` callback that updates the database state when it is toggled.

The problem is that the checkbox loses state when an item is scrolled off and back on screen, because the view is being rebuilt from stale cursor data.

I understand that the preferred solution here is to dump and re-fetch the cursor every time data changes. This just strikes me as painfully inefficient. When a checkbox is toggled, literally one bit of data has changed in my result set. Throwing away the entire cursor feels like overkill.

An alternative I've tried is to cache the `completed` flag, update the database and the cache when an item is toggled, and check the cache in `bindView`. This works, but it feels kludgy.

Am I missing something here? Is there a better pattern than the ones above? Am I overestimating the cost of expiring the cursor every time a tiny change occurs?

Comment: What do you expect? Your second alternative is how I would implement it. You could however extend `View` to create the items of your `ListView` and implement some sort of "binding" mechanism which would automatically update the database on changes to that View. But that strikes me as overly complicated for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about the efficiency of cursor refreshes based on user input. This is a constant cost and you will not notice it.

Another way is to override setViewValue and set those checkboxes by hand. Below you can find an idea of how you could do that.

```
public class MyViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

    int viewId = view.getId();
    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.flag:

            // Sett the flag based on e.g. an array you have with the states

            return true;
            break;

        default:
            // There is no specific way of showing this, hence go for default
            return = false;
    }
  }
}
```